# I cannot connect to IPython notebook running on the AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I am running an AWS EC2 GPU instance. And I setup iPython notebook on this instance follow the [tutorial](http://randyzwitch.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/cluster-computing-ipython-ec2.pdf).

At the last step, I used this command:

```
sudo ipython notebook --profile=nbserver
```

to start iPython notebook. It seems OK. The output information is:

```
[I 14:14:30.214 NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
[I 14:14:30.230 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/ubuntu
[I 14:14:30.230 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 14:14:30.230 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: https://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/
[I 14:14:30.230 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

However, I use my browser to launch the remote iPython notebook:

```
https://ec2-54-66-247-201.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8888/
```

But I fail on this step. I have no idea. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8):

You will need to open port 8888 for Inbound traffic in the Security Group associated with your Amazon EC2 instance.

[image: Security Group rules]